# INVALID_REQUEST_BODY when trying to get Sender View URL using SOBO

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using send on behalf of (SOBO) to create an envelope, which works fine.

I'm able to get the envelopeId.  But when I attempt to use the base URL that was used for creating the envelop and add on the added "/{envelopeId}/views/sender" before posting I get INVALID_REQUEST_BODY.

The documentation show that there is only one item for the request body... returnUrl as seen here  https://iodocs.docusign.com/# "Views -> Sender" section

```
'POST http://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender

            '/envelopes is already part of the base url because of creation of the envelope
            url = url + "/" & strEnvelopeID & "/views/sender"
strBody = "<returnUrl>https://www.google.com</returnUrl>"
request = initializeRequest(url, "POST", strBody, strUserName, strPassword, strIntegratorKey)
```

Comment: I guess I didn’t explain enough of what I’m attempting to do and what is working and what is not.

I have a web application that has 100’s of sales users.  The application is integrated with DocuSign using the SOBO (Send On Behalf Of).  This is where one application login can be created for the corporate business entity that can login and create Envelopes on behalf of any of the sales user.  This makes it so that the custom web application doesn’t need to store nor maintain each of the sales users DocuSign passwords.

Comment: So when I create an envelope with a status of “create” using the SOBO, I would like to provide a link for the Sales user to click on that will automatically take them to the “Sender View” or “Sender Console” where they can add more documents as needed…and also add more tags as necessary before they decided to send of the contract out to the client.

When using the SOBO to create the Envelope I have access to both the base url and the new EnvelopId…

http://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/

Comment: So the question now is how does one get the AccountId of the “Sender User” using SOBO so that I can generate the  EmbededSendingView URL without knowing the sender password?  Because the createEmbeddedSendingViewTest() show that you must login as the sender and get their AccountId (which is part of the base URL once logged in) before you can do a post to get the url for the sender view.

Comment: I attempted to simply append the following string to the base user “envelopes/envelopeId/views/sender” and then do a post asking for the url.  This is where I get an error.  I know that I’m missing something… it doesn’t make sense to have to log back into the system as the sender to get the “Sender View” url, especially when I already have the envelopeId and I’m logged in on their behalf?  What am I missing?  This should be a common thing.

Comment: Deleted my answer, apologies for misreading. You are correct that returnUrl is only value for POST sender view.